# Displaying 4 complex random divs from array list

Tags: php, html, random

I am trying to make a carousel which displays 4 random posts. I came across a simple random div display from another thread

```
$divs = array(
'<div id="divZero">Start Div</div>',
'<div id="divFirst">First Div</div>',
'<div id="divSecond">Second Div</div>',
'<div id="divThird">Third Div</div>',
'<div id="divFourth">Fourth Div</div>',
'<div id="divFifth">Fifth Div</div>',
'<div id="divSixth">Sixth Div</div>'
);

// Array with 4 random keys from $divs
$randKeys = array_rand($divs, 4);

echo $divs[$randKeys[0]]; // First random div
echo $divs[$randKeys[1]]; // Second random div
echo $divs[$randKeys[2]]; // Third random div
echo $divs[$randKeys[3]]; // Fourth random div
```

The problem is I am using classes for the divs and the wrapping is not simple, and I am incorporating Google Analytics tracking code. When I try it with my div set up, I get the **417 - Expectation Failed** error. Was wondering if anyone might be able to help me sort this out.

The divs use class formats since they repeat, but the link, title (and GA label names) change. Here is an example of 2

```
<div class="rec-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="rw-image"><a href="https://www.website.com/linkA" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Evergreen', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Story Title A'});"><img src="https://website.com/imageA.jpg" width="80" height="80"></a></div>
    <div class="rw-title"><a href="https://www.website.com/linkA" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Evergreen', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Story Title A'});">Story Title A</a></div>
</div>

<div class="rec-wrap clearfix">
    <div class="rw-image"><a href="https://www.website.com/linkB" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Evergreen', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Story Title B'});"><img src="https://website.com/imageB.jpg" width="80" height="80"></a></div>
    <div class="rw-title"><a href="https://www.website.com/linkB" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Evergreen', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Story Title B'});">Story Title B</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an array filled with marked up output, create an array of posts data.

Your posts either stored in the database nor is static, if it is static, then you can create the posts data as below:

```
$posts = [
    ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'Story A', 'image_name' => 'imageA', 'link' => 'StoryALink'],
    ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'Story B', 'image_name' => 'imageB', 'link' => 'StoryBLink'],
    ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'Story C', 'image_name' => 'imageC', 'link' => 'StoryCLink']
];
```

Now, you want to echo these posts randomly, so you can do that by a foreach loop:

```
foreach(array_rand($posts, 2) as $index) {
    $post = $posts[$index];

    echo '
        <div>
            <h1>
                <a href="https://www.website.com/', $post['link'], '">', $post['title'], '</a>
            </h1>
            <a href="https://www.website.com/', $post['link'], '">
                <img src="https://website.com/', $post['image_name'],'.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>';
}
```

change the markup as you want.

If your posts stored in the database, you should select them randomly by query and then you can echo them by below code:

```
while($post = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '
        <div>
            <h1>
                <a href="https://www.website.com/', $post['link'], '">', $post['title'], '</a>
            </h1>
            <a href="https://www.website.com/', $post['link'], '">
                <img src="https://website.com/', $post['image_name'],'.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>';
}
```